# Facebook deteremines OG image but doesn't show it

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm wonder why Facebook could determine OG image but won't show it.

try to debug `http://www.afdesta.net/profile/1539/4/` using [Facebook debug tools](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object)

The [image exists](http://www.afdesta.net/static/plugins!12afdesta!12avatars!12users!121539!121539_200x.jpg/) and Facebook could determine but won't show it.

Comment: The `og:image` is empty when i tried debugging the [url](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.afdesta.net%2Fprofile%2F1539%2F4%2F)

Comment: Try use something like Firebug and you see that image URL has been fetched or even click on white space in front of `og:image`

Comment: Please check my current answer (as of June-2017) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44713512/147618

Answer (score 0):

One reason was likely and was that Facebook escapes and encodes URLs assigned to `og:image` meta tags. So we have to have a clean url with no special character in it.

Now i changed url format and problem has just gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the name of your images without spaces. Maybe you image url is now somenthing like...
www.ejemplo.com/IMAGES/image one.jpg

and would be...
www.ejemplo.com/IMAGES/image_one.jpg