# Facebook open graph og:image escape whitespace characters

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a page with user submitted photo galleries. I'm using the facebook API to share the photos. It shares the page with a query string. When the query string is present, it sets all the open graph properties on the page . This works great except when the image has white space characters on the file name.

I have tried replacing the whitespace characters with '%20' as so

```
http://example.com/gallery/images/large/this image.jpg
```

to

```
 http://example.com/gallery/images/large/this%20image.jpg
```

But the facebook parser doesn't like that either.

Is there a way to scape these characters or am I going to have to go back and change it so that it replaces when the images get uploaded?

Comment: you really should not use whitespace in filenames at all...that´s the best way to fix it, and it will prevent you from a lot of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question (being it old), Now (in June-2017) Facebook parser works with whitespace characters when escaped with '%20', hope it would help someone looking for solution.

So, convert whitespace to %20 as depicted below:

```
http://example.com/gallery/images/large/this image.jpg
```

to

```
http://example.com/gallery/images/large/this%20image.jpg
```

Server side language has pre-defined function for that e.g. [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. The facebook parser doesn't take whitespaces into account. Even if you use a redirect you will have issues later on. So it's better to just adjust your URLs now.